# How to add some numbers inputed by the user given a specific formula

Tags: c++, for-loop

So i need to write a program that asks for some numbers from the user (the amount of numbers is determined by the user) and then add them given this formula: ANSWER = FIRST - SECOND + THIRD - FIFTH + ...

where FIRST, SECOND, etc are the first, second and the rest of the numbers input by the user.

The problem is that i can create a loop that stores the numbers but actually, it only updates the value of the "num" variable. This is the code i have written.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int num, counter;
double answer;

cout << "Enter integer count: ";
cin >> counter;

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin >> num;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about storing these numbers in a `std::vector`?

Comment: You need an `array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: You don't need to store each number, you just need a flag to say whether to add or subtract each number. Then flip that flag. Remember to initialise answer to 0 before your loop if you do that.

Comment: What happened to the fourth number?

Comment: what if you use directly the module of i to know if you need to subtract or to add? i%2 is zero for odd values of i.

Comment: @interjay thats how the answer is supposed to be

Comment: @Johan if the fourth value was not leaved for mistake we need to know what is the sequence of "indices" you want to use for your `answer`.

Comment: @RobertoTrani that's the question i've been given by my professor. that's all i know

Comment: @Johan I think it was a mistake, and if it is not so, and you think that the original question was to discard only the fourth value you can skip it putting `if (i==3) continue;` just after `cin >> num;`. In this way you don't put the fourth value in your answer.

Comment: @RobertoTrani it maybe be that or what i thought is a bit more different, i thought the formula is like: first - second + third - fifth + sixth - ninth... , so the difference between the two numbers between the +...+ becomes +1 bigger everytime.

Comment: You only saw it grow by +1 once. You can't extrapolate from that. Either it's a mistake and should say "fourth", or there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Agreed. I'm deleting my answer based on there not being enough information in the question to actually answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a if-else clause that controls the *remainder of the integer division of index i by 2*  you can separate even and odd cases to obtain the desidered effect

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int num, counter;
double answer;

cout << "Enter integer count: ";
cin >> counter;

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin >> num;
    if(i%2==0)
      answer+=num;
    else
      answer-=num;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this assuming you don't need to store the numbers input by the user. What I am basically doing is just toggling between `+1` and `-1` that I then multiply by the number input by the user and then straightforwardly adding it to the `answer`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int num, counter;
    double answer = 0;

    cout << "Enter integer count: ";
    cin >> counter;

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> num;
        answer  += num*pow(-1, i);
    }
    cout<<answer;

return 0;
}
```

You can also do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int num, counter;
    double answer = 0;

    cout << "Enter integer count: ";
    cin >> counter;

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> num;
        if(i%2 == 0)answer  += num;
        else    answer -= num;
    }
    cout<<answer;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain your solution a bit. I like this solution that alternates the sign using the pows of -1 :)

Comment: `pow` is a bit heavyweight for this - it's designed for a `double` raised to another `double`.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the comment. I have given an alternate method for it.